# ColdFusion - Converting weight in pounds to pounds and ounces

Tags: coldfusion

I am writing a little conversion piece in ColdFusion CFSCRIPT.

I need to convert a weight in pounds to pounds and ounces.

So, 3.1565 needs to become 3 pounds and 3 ounces.  1.512 will become 1 pound and 9 ounces (round up the ounces).
0.25 will become 0 pounds and 4 ounces.

My thought is to take the total weight in pounds and multiply it by sixteen, which will give me the total ounces. Then I'll need to extract the even pounds by dividing by sixteen and the remainder will be the ounces.  I really don't know how to do this accurately and with efficient code.

```
<cfscript>
MyPounds = 0;
MyOunces = 0;
ThisPounds = 2.12345;
MyOunces = (ThisPounds * 16);
// EXTRACT THE NUMBER OF POUNDS

// REMAINDER IS OUNCES - ROUND UP 


}
</cfscript>
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Something like this (not extensively tested).

**EDIT:**  If the input can be negative, use the `abs()` value for calculations

```
<cfset theInput  = 0.25>
<!--- round down to get total pounds --->
<cfset lbs       = int(theInput)>
<!--- extract remainder. multiply by 16 and round up --->
<cfset ounces    = ceiling((theInput - lbs)  * 16)>
<cfoutput>#lbs# pounds #ounces# ounces</cfoutput>
```

Comment: This seems to work really well.  Thanks.  And thanks for commenting too.

Answer (score 1):

Integer division and Modulus should give you the values you need.

```
<cfscript>
MyPounds = 0;
MyOunces = 0;
ThisPounds = 2.12345;
MyOunces = (ThisPounds * 16);
// EXTRACT THE NUMBER OF POUNDS
weightInPounds = MyOunces \ 16;
// REMAINDER IS OUNCES - ROUND UP 
remainderOunces = ceiling(MyOunces MOD 16);
</cfscript>
```

Answer (score 0):

This should do it:

```
<cffunction name="PoundConverter" returntype="string">
    <cfargument name="Pounds" type="numeric" required="true" hint="" />
    <cfset var TotalPounds = Fix(Arguments.Pounds) />
    <cfset var TotalOunces = Ceiling((Arguments.Pounds - TotalPounds) * 16) />
    <cfreturn TotalPounds & " pounds and " & TotalOunces & " ounces" />
</cffunction>


<cfoutput>
    #PoundConverter(3.1565)#<br />
    #PoundConverter(1.512)#
</cfoutput>
```

Comment: Feel like submitting it to cflib.org? I did not see a function for this.

Comment: If you submit it, the only thing I'd change (in both yours and mine) is to have it return a struct with keys for "pounds" and "ounces".  That'd make the function a lot more reusable than having it return a string.  IMO, of course :)

Comment: Yeah, I'd probably break into one that returns the two values, and another that returns them formatted for display, with the option to exclude 0 values, so for .5 pounds, you'd get back "8 ounces" if that was what you wanted :)

Comment: @charliegriefer & Dan - Yep, I vote for a structure too. Just add abs() for handling negative values and it sounds good.

Answer (score 0):

You pretty much have what you need.  To extract the number of pounds, divide by 16.  The remainder (the "mod") is the ounces.

```
<cfscript>
    function poundsandounces( initvalue ) {
        var rawvalue = val( initvalue ) * 16;
        var lbs = int( rawvalue / 16 );
        var oz = ceiling( rawvalue % 16 );
        return "#lbs# pounds #oz# ounces";
    }
</cfscript>

<cfoutput>#poundsandounces( 0.25 )#</cfoutput>
```